# How can I delete detail data in nested objects in flutter/dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, jsonserializer

I have a json data like this
{key:value, key:value, detail:[{key:value, key:value, ...}]}

I want to delete the detail array in this data and throw the remaining elements into another json object, how can I do that?

I tried two ways as below but it doesn't work:

```
var master =(delivery.deliveryTemp?.toJson() as Map<String, dynamic>).removeWhere((key, value) => key != "detail" || value == null);
```

`var master= delivery.deliveryTemp?.toJson().remove("detail");`

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I solved it.**

```
   var master= delivery.deliveryTemp?.toJson();
   master?.removeWhere((key, value) => key=="detail");
```